# Order Status post method not getting called web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

My Post command is not getting hit when using postman. The post comamnd is used to change the order status of a delivery

```
namespace DeliveryGo.Controllers
{
    public class DeliveryController : ApiController
    {


        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            string retJson;
            string constring = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DeliveryGocs"].ToString();   


            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Deliverys AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN  DeliveryLines AS B ON A.id = B.DeliveryId;";

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                var orderDictionary = new Dictionary<int, DeliverysItems>();


                var list = connection.Query<DeliverysItems, DeliverItemLines, DeliverysItems>(
                    sql,
                    (order, orderDetail) =>
                    {
                        DeliverysItems orderEntry;

                        if (!orderDictionary.TryGetValue(order.id, out orderEntry))
                        {
                            orderEntry = order;
                            orderEntry.DeliveryLines = new List<DeliverItemLines>();
                            orderDictionary.Add(orderEntry.id, orderEntry);
                        }

                        orderEntry.DeliveryLines.Add(orderDetail);
                        return orderEntry;
                    })
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();


                retJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);

                if (list.Count > 0)
                {
                    var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    response.Content = new StringContent(retJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    return ResponseMessage(response);
                }else
                {
                    var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
                    response.Content = new StringContent(retJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    return ResponseMessage(response);

                }



            }
        }
        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void ChangeOrderStatus(int  enumValue, string SopOrderNumber)
        {


            //lets get the order status here
            int orderStatus = (int)enumValue;

            string connectionString = Constants.DeliveryGocs;
            using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                string sql = "UPDATE Deliverys SET OrderStatus = +"+enumValue+ " WHERE SopOrderNumber ='" +SopOrderNumber +"'";
                db.Execute(sql);



            }
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see I am calling the method in postman with the values in the form parameters but when I debug my breakpoint inside the method is not getting hit am i doing something wrong.

[image]

I am posting my web route  here as see that what most request.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: wish someon would stop donwvotting me i provided plenty of code and evidence !

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving 204 and it's a success for when you don't return any response from your POST method. it indicates a hit to me. but you said it's not hitting the method, if you mean a break point hit it might be because of assembly issues between runtime and existing binaries. but generally it looks like a hit to me :)

Comment: @prd do you no has to why its not getting hit ?.